# Spring Data Cassandra LocalDateTime Conversion

Tags: java, datetime, converters, java-8, spring-data-cassandra

I'm working on a project where we have an entity we want to persist with a field of type LocalDateTime, we know cassandra does not have native support for this type conversion, we've created our own custom converter using Spring's support for converters, however it seems Spring-Data-Cassandra is unable to either recognise them or understand that the field should be mapped to a column.

This is how we've registered our converters with Spring's  conversion service.

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <set>
                <!-- list of converters-->
                <bean class="com.klappo.userservice.api.persistence.converters.DateToLocalDateTimeConverter" />
                <bean class="com.klappo.userservice.api.persistence.converters.LocalDateTimeToDateConverter" />
                <bean class="com.klappo.userservice.api.persistence.converters.DateToLocalDateConverter" />
                <bean class="com.klappo.userservice.api.persistence.converters.LocalDateToDateConverter" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The end result is the following exception thrown on startup of our application:

```
    Caused by: 
org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions: java.time.LocalDate:|Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation|
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.verify(BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java:45)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntity.verify(BasicCassandraPersistentEntity.java:198)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:426)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:607)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:294)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:426)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:607)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:294)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:256)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:372)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext.initialize(BasicCassandraMappingContext.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMappingContext.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
```

Spring's data documentation on this is lacking quite a bit, so we're wondering if anyone has attempted to use custom type converters with spring-data-cassandra and if so, we'd like to know what's the right way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunatey the spring-data-cassandra ver. <= 1.2.x could be used only with beans which could be directly mapped to datatypes from this list:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/java-driver/reference/javaClass2Cql3Datatypes_r.html

I met the same problem, because wanted to map my classes into TEXT fields in Cassandra, but couldn't do it. After several days of trying I came to the conclusion that it is not possible to use custom type converters in Spring-Data for Cassandra (tested with version 1.2.0.M1).

CassandraTemplate uses MappingCassandraConverter which has embedded DefaultConversionService, but this DefaultConversionService is not used anywhere in the spring-data-cassandra module. It was introduced only for integration with SpringData API.

You could find in the code of library that conversionService is using only in

```
BeanWrapper<S> wrapper = BeanWrapper.create(instance, conversionService);
```

which just skips conversionService:

```
@Deprecated
public static <T> BeanWrapper<T> create(T bean, ConversionService conversionService) {
    return new BeanWrapper<T>(bean);
}
```

You could see in MappingCassandraConverter.readPropertyFromRow(...) which uses ColumnReader.get(int i) where supported only Cassandra's MAP, LIST, SET and primary data types (Text, Numbers, UUID, java.util.Date, Boolean, ByteBuffer).

In addition BasicCassandraMappingContext.verifier (BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier) throw exception on attempt to write any field which could not be mapped to supported types of Cassandra or is not @Table.

That's why you had the the exception

```
// it was attempt to check conversion of an embedded field 'date' in LocalDateTime    
org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions: java.time.LocalDate
```

So the only way to solve it is using ConversionService on top of spring-data-cassandra for your needs.

Sample code for conversion service part:

```
import org.springframework.data.convert.Jsr310Converters;

...    

@Bean
public ConversionService getConversionService() {
    // creates DefaultConversionService
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    bean.setConverters(new HashSet<>(getConverters()));
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();
    ConversionService service = bean.getObject();
    return service;
}

private Set<Converter<?, ?>> getConverters() {
    Set<Converter<?,?>> converters = new HashSet<Converter<?,?>>();
    converters.addAll(Jsr310Converters.getConvertersToRegister());
    converters.add(new TimeWriteConverter());
    converters.add(new TimeReadConverter());

    return converters;
}

public static class TimeWriteConverter implements Converter<LocalDateTime, Long> {
    @Override
    public Long convert(LocalDateTime source) {
        return source.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    }
}
public static class TimeReadConverter implements Converter<Long, LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(Long source) {
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(source), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any workaround, or how did you implement your mappings after finding this problem?

Comment: Yes, I've added additional service layer which uses ConversionService programmatically. It's fine for my case, because in my project is required some sort of time-series API (findLatest, findRange). It looks like http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-programmatic-usage

Answer (score 2):

I can see some differences from my configuration.

First of all why use `set` when you can use the standard configuration container `list`.

Second: if it doesn't work try java code config and see if it works:

```
@Configuration
public class ConversionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConversionService getConversionService() {
        ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
        bean.setConverters(getConverters());
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        ConversionService object = bean.getObject();
        return object;
    }

    private Set<Converter> getConverters() {
        Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<Converter>();

        converters.add(new DateToLocalDateTimeConverter());
        converters.add(new LocalDateTimeToDateConverter());
        converters.add(new DateToLocalDateConverter());
        converters.add(new LocalDateToDateConverter());

        return converters;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why java config would behave differently than xml for this case?

Comment: @JörnHorstmann The sole problem with XML is that you have to wait until runtime to discover typos in a bean or some other stupid boo-boo. On the other side, using Spring IDE plugin (or the integrated Spring Tools Suite) definitely can help you there with the mistakes implemented and make sure of the configurations integrity.

Comment: From my point of view, there is no practical difference between XML and annotation-based configuration, because any modern IDE supports checking of configuration (Intelij IDEA - Spring* plugins, Eclipse - Spring Tool Suite plugin). For example any XML in Spring configuration usually well-covered by XSD schema, so typos discovered on early stages of development.

Comment: @DmitryBuykin Your thoughtful comments have dramatically enlarged the scope of my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have the same issue, I would like to share some further results of my investigations:

- The verifier of spring data cassandra checks the validity of the entity class, which failes, because the field type LocalDateTime is not a valid simple type
- Thanks to the bad implementation of cassandra mapping, it is very cumbersome to overwrite/extend the functionality with own implementations. Espacially the `CassandraSimpleTypeHolder` has some final and static methods, which are directly used in other classes.
- I tried to provide my own implementations of `CassandraMappingContext`, `CassandraPersistentProperty` and so on. This allows to "verify" the entity, but writing is not possible. This is due to the used datastax driver, which does not know LocalDateTime in its internal mapping `TypeCode`. So you have to provide the mapping between LocalDateTime and Date. This is normaly done by the ConversionService. But for now I don't find any place where this is used.

However, another option is to wait for the official solution:

- Internally the datastax driver is used. The current version 3.0 has the possibility to handle jdk8 stuff using an extra-module: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-java-driver-3-0-0-released
- But, the 3.0 driver and the compability to JSR310 is not supported in the current spring data release. It will be part of the next spring data release: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls